# How to get an average value of two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

How can I query two tables in order to get average value of flies per each day of period where pilot passed study?

```
flies 
pilot_id    flies   date
101        6       01.04.2018
102        3       02.04.2018
150        1       03.04.2018
216        2       25.04.2018
```

2.

```
passed_study
pilot_id 
100
101
102
103
```

The result must be: (6+3)/2=4,5.

Unfortunatelly my query gives wrong result...Thanks!

Comment: pilots with flies? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a simple `join` and `avg()`:

```
select avg(f.flies)
from flies f join
     passed_study ps
     on ps.pilot_id = f.pilot_id;
```

Comment: thanks.
In my real database (about 9000 rows), I made such query and cheked a result in Excel. The results were different, unfortunately...

    I used this code:

    select date, avg(flies) AS
 average_flies 
from passed_study inner join
     flies
     on passed_study.pilot_id = flies.pilot_id
where activity.login_time between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-02' 
group by flies.date;


What do I wrong?